# Object not applicable in MIT Scheme (a different Ackermann's function)

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, mit-scheme, ackermann

I found this version of Ackermann's function and tried to code it in MIT Scheme Lisp with no success:

> The Ackermann Function A(m,n)
>
> When m=0
>
> A(m,n)=n+1
>
> When m>0 and n=0
>
> A(m,n)=A(m-1,1)
>
> When m>0 and n>0
>
> A(m,n)=A(m-1,A(m,n-1))

(found here http://www.gfredericks.com/sandbox/arith/ackermann)

My Scheme code:

```
(define (acker2 m n)
        (cond ((= m 0)
               (+ n 1))
              ((and (> m 0)
                    (= n 0))
               (acker2 (- m 1)
                       1))
              ((and (> m 0)
                    (> n 0))
               (acker2 (- m 1)
                       (acker2 (m
                               (- n 1)))))))
```

Now some results:

(acker2 0 0)
value: 1

(acker2 0 1)
value: 2

(acker2 0 2)
value: 3

(acker2 2 2)
object 2 is not applicable

(acker2 1 23)
object 1 is not applicable

(acker2 8 0)
object 7 is not applicable

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error (too many parentheses) in the last expression:

```
(acker2 (m (- n 1)))
```

this should be:

```
(acker2 m (- n 1))
```

Remember that in Lisp/Scheme `(a b1 b2 ...)` means “apply the function `a` to the arguments `b1 b2 ...`”. The message “object 2 is not applicable” means exactly this: `m` is equal to 2 and the system tries to apply it to `(- n 1)`. But the number 2 (“the object 2”) is not a function (“is not applicable”).